# The record 999 can not be retrieved

Tags: cakephp

In my sample database table, I have a record with post id 999.
I got a few lines of code to retrieve the record of post id 999:

```
function viewing($sid){    
$this->Testing->post_id=$sid;
$this->set('posts', $this->Testing->read());
}
```

But no record can be record retrieved from the post with id 999 when I altered the code:

```
function viewing($sid){ 
$sid=999;   
$this->Testing->post_id=$sid;
$this->set('posts', $this->Testing->read());
}
```

Could you tell help me please?

Comment: Which one is it, `Site1` or `Testing`? This won't do anything as-is.

Comment: Your example code is very confusing. Which model is the controller controlling? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you messing the terms and functions. First you set id of the Site1 model. Then you trying to read record from the Testing model and setting post_id in the record. The proper code should look like:

```
function viewing($sid){ 
  $sid=999;   
  $this->Post->id=$sid;
  $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
}
```

Alternatively and more short it will be:

```
function viewing($sid){ 
  $sid=999;   
  $this->set('post', $this->Post->read(null, $sid));
}
```

But assuming that you want to get posts probably the actual code should look like:

```
function viewing($sid){ 
  $sid=999;   
  $this->set('post', $this->Posts->fund('all', array('conditions'=>array('post_id'=>$sid))));
}
```

Or something similar. I think first you should take a look on the [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/) and on the [CakePHP API](http://api.cakephp.org)

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I want.
Thank you, Nik.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the model::id attribute, not post_id.

$this->Site1->id=$sid;

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the form `$this->Post->read(null, $sid)`

If you want to control retrieval of associated tables, use `$this->MyModel->contain()`

E.g.

`$this->Post->contain('Testing') //(Post & Testing but not Site1)`

or

```
$this->Post->contain('Testing','Site1.someValue') //(Post & Testing and Site1.someValue)
```

I think you should also carefully reread the manual sections on http://book.cakephp.org/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together & http://book.cakephp.org/view/73/Retrieving-Your-Data